# How to get the records with the combination of Year and Created Date in the SOQL?

Tags: soql, query

I am working on one requirement to display records on the LWC data table by fetching them using the combination of Year (picklist field) and Created Date.
Suppose if table has below records:

```
 1. Year = 2022 and createdDate = 4/5/2023
 2. Year = 2021 and createdDate = 5/5/2023
 3. Year = null and createdDate = 4/5/2023
 4. Year = null and createdDate = 8/6/2023
 5. Year = 2013 and CreatedDate = 3/4/2015
```

I want to show the records in the Data table as below order. Year null values should come first

```
Year = null and createdDate = 8/6/2023

Year = null and createdDate = 5/5/2023

Year = 2022 and createdDate = 4/5/2023

Year = 2021 and createdDate = 1/1/2023

Year = 2013 and CreatedDate = 3/4/2015
```

I tried below query, but it is giving NULLS last instead of first.

```
select Id, Year__c,DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) from Account where RecordType.Name = 'Prospect' group by id,Year__c,DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) ORDER BY DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) DESC, Year__c DESC NULLS first
```